# Python script to create blank docx file fails on non-Latin character input

Tags: python, encoding

I wrote a script that creates a blank `.docx` file on the basis of another file, taking only the filename of that file and adding `_EN` to the end of it.

It works fine on all files, except if there are non-Latin characters in the filename. I've tried adding `.encode('UTF-8')` to line 7, but it doesn't work.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import re
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

docname = str((sys.argv[1]))
chopped = re.sub(r"(^.*)\..*", r"\1", docname)
newname = (chopped + '_EN.docx')
document = Document()
paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
paragraph_format = paragraph.paragraph_format
paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(0)
paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(0)
style = document.styles['Normal']
font = style.font
font.name = 'Times New Roman'
font.size = Pt(10.5)
document.save(newname)
```

As you can see, I've included the encoding line at the beginning.

Edit: thanks to advice from one of the commenters, I can elicit the error:

```
C:\Users\marca\OneDrive\programming\python\apps> python doc_creator.py 04.メガほむら変身後.pm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "doc_creator.py", line 18, in <module>
    document.save(newname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\document.py", line 142, in save
    self._part.save(path_or_stream)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\parts\document.py", line 128, in save
    self.package.save(path_or_stream)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\package.py", line 160, in save
    PackageWriter.write(pkg_file, self.rels, self.parts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\pkgwriter.py", line 32, in write
    phys_writer = PhysPkgWriter(pkg_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\phys_pkg.py", line 141, in __init__
    self._zipf = ZipFile(pkg_file, 'w', compression=ZIP_DEFLATED)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 756, in __init__
    self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: '04.????????_EN.docx'
```

(Interestingly, the filename I copied in appears as squares with question marks in them in Powershell, but when I copied it out of Powershell and pasted it back in here, it was correctly encoded, indicating that Powershell at least is reading the characters correctly, even if it can't display them.)

Comment: Please include the error you are seeing?

Comment: I put it in the registry and run it by right-clicking on the filename and selecting the script. It simply fails without displaying an error. I can't run it from the command-line (Powershell) because I can't even enter Japanese characters (as in the IME simply won't let me switch to Japanese), so I can't pass a Japanese filename as an argument to test it.

Comment: Try copying the filename from somewhere. You can then paste it into Powershell. I tried with `04.メガほむら変身後.pmd` from [a loosely related question](http://superuser.com/questions/554108/extracting-a-zip-file-with-japanese-filenames) and although it displays squares in Powershell itself, checking with the Explorer shows it worked anyway.